# how to add css when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I add css when a button is clicked jquery?

I want to create when I click the button it will toggle hide my div and rotate the arrow to 90 degree and when a click again it will toggle show my div and rotate the arrow to -90 degree.

Here's what I've tried:

```js
$("#toogle_menu").click(function() {
  $("#jy_nav_pos_main").slideToggle("slow"),
    $("#toogle_menu").css({
      transform: "rotate(-90deg)"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs row margin_auto" id="jy_nav_pos_main" role="tablist">
  <li>menu</li>
</ul>
<button id="toogle_menu" class="btn btn-light">
    &raquo;
</button>
```

Comment: You don't have any *div* element!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the style in each click, [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) the class `$( "#toogle_menu" ).toggleClass( "toggled" )` and style this class in css

```js
$("#toogle_menu").click(function() {
  $("#jy_nav_pos_main").slideToggle("slow"),
    $("#toogle_menu").toggleClass("toggled")
});
```

```css
.toggled {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs row margin_auto" id="jy_nav_pos_main" role="tablist">
  ......
</ul>
<button id="toogle_menu" class="btn btn-light">
&raquo;
</button>
```

Comment: not working on me, my code like this https://jsfiddle.net/sqfeonwh/ im already have css on toggle, so i add more css but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```js
var clicked = false;
$("#toogle_menu").click(function() {
 var deg = clicked ? 0 : -90;
  $("#jy_nav_pos_main").slideToggle("slow"),
 
    $("#toogle_menu").css({
      transform: "rotate("+deg+"deg)"
    });
    clicked = !clicked;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs row margin_auto" id="jy_nav_pos_main" role="tablist">
  <li>menu</li>
</ul>
<button id="toogle_menu" class="btn btn-light">
    &raquo;
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<style type="text/css">
    .nav{
        display: none;
    }
    .rotate{
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
        transition: all 0.4s linear;
    }
    #clickBtn span{
        transition: all 0.4s linear;
    }
</style>
<button type="button" id="clickBtn">Click &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></button>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs row margin_auto" id="jy_nav_pos_main" role="tablist">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#clickBtn").on('click',function(){
            $(this).find('span').toggleClass('rotate');
            $(".nav").slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  You can provide a more rounded answer by 1) providing commentary on what changes to make / how this fixes the issue  2) adding your code as a working snippet.  For questions like this, people will tend towards answers where they can see it working with no effort.